# sequence of functions of sin and cos converges pointwisely but not uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, sequence-of-function

I will write my problem and my approach in detail as I am not really comfortable with sequences of functions and analyzing their convergence, any feedback or improvement is appreciated. I am asked to investigate the convergence and type of convergence of the sequence $(\sin\frac{x}{n},\cos\frac{x}{n})_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. I investigate the coordinate sequences separately:

For the first coordinate, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \left| \sin\frac{x}{n}  \right|  \le \left| x \right| \frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow 0$, so the sequence $(\sin\frac{x}{n})_{n}$ converges pointwisely to the zero function.

For the second, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \left| \cos\frac{x}{n} -1 \right| = \left| \cos\frac{x}{n} -\cos0 \right|   \le  \left| \frac{x}{n} - 0\right| = \left| x \right| \frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow 0$. Thus, the sequence $(\cos\frac{x}{n})_{n}$ converges pointwisely to the constant function $1$.

From these two, I concluded that the sequence $(\sin\frac{x}{n},\cos\frac{x}{n})_{n}$ converges pointwisely to the function $f(x)=(0,1)$.

However, this convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$ because one of the coordinate convergences is not uniform: $ \left| \left|  \sin\frac{x}{n} - 0 \right| \right| _{\infty } = \underset{x\in \mathbb{R}}{\text{sup}} \left| \sin\frac{x}{n}  \right| =1 \nrightarrow 0 $.

Is this line of arguments correct? When showing both pointwise convergence and uniform divergence I used the coordinate sequences, is this valid?

Comment: You used the fact that for $\frac xn$ small enough,  $\sin \frac{x}{n} \approx \frac xn$.  Similarly $\cos \frac xn -1 \approx -\frac12(\frac xn)^2$.

Comment: Your proof can be justified using the following: $|x-u|\leq \|(x,y)-(u,v)\|\leq |x-u|+|y-v|$